# PHP - MYSQLI - Prepared statements - Looping though results to obtain values to total?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I am attempting to code a shopping cart, more specifically though the totaling of items that have been added to the shopping cart.

I have some code that is supposed to add the products price to variable that is "the order total".

It checks to see if there are values inside of a session variable, then checks those "id's" against result row id's stored in a mysql table. For each id in the session value the corresponding price is added to the total.

If there is a special price existing for this item, that price becomes the price.

Now what actually happens here though, is that when I add one item to the cart. It totals it no problem. When I add two items to the cart, I only see the total value of the first item that was added to the cart.

As this is a conversion of some old code (into a prepared statement) I am assuming that somewhere along the ling I have missed some crucial aspect of this... Something like `mysqli_data_seek`.

As my knowledge of prepared statements at the moment is not great, I could be making in error in the way the loop comes about.

If anyone could go though this and spot the problem in what I have coded, or perhaps provide some info on how I could accomplish this task in a better way... It would all be very greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['orderItem']) && count($_SESSION['orderItem']) > 0)
{
    $ordersItem = sanitize($_SESSION['orderItem']);
    $ordersItemJoined = join($ordersItem, ',');
    if ($stmt = $link->prepare("
        SELECT i.id, i.price, s.specialPrice, s.start, s.end 
        FROM items i
        LEFT JOIN item_specials s
        ON s.id = i.id
        WHERE i.id 
        IN (?)
    "))
    {   
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $ordersItemJoined);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($itemsId, $itemsPrice, $itemsSpecialPrice, $itemsSpecialStart, $itemsSpecialEnd);

        while ($stmt->fetch())
        {
            // Apply sale price if it exists
            if ($itemsSpecialPrice > 0)
            {
                if ( ($itemsSpecialStart < date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) && ($itemsSpecialEnd > date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) )
                {
                    $itemsPrice = $itemsSpecialPrice;
                }
            }

            $itemsQuantity = sanitize($_SESSION['itemQuantity'][$itemsId]);
            foreach ($ordersItem as $itemToTotal)
            {
                if ($itemToTotal == $itemsId) 
                {
                    $cartTotal += $itemsPrice*$itemsQuantity;
                }
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Prepared statements do not work properly for `IN (?)` type things. The placeholders are literally treated as a SINGLE value. Inserting a bunch of comma-separated values does not get it treated as a bunch of commas-seperated values. it'll just be a monolithic single string. It'll be treated as `where x='1,2,3'`, and not `where x in (1,2,3)`.

Comment: @MarcB Hmm, okay thank you very much, I understand what you are saying... But that doesn't make things any easier. Surely these values should be prepared in this manner so I mean... How would I go about trying to accomplish something like that?

Comment: if this is on mysql, you can use `FIND_IN_SET()`, where a prepared statement and single placeholder would work. Otherwise, the usual workaround for this is to dynamically build a `?,?,?,?,...` string to match however many values you're using in the `in()` clause and build your query string on the fly. painful, but this is one major place where prepared statements/placeholders fall flat on their face and bleed on everything.

Comment: @MarcB Alright thanks a lot. I am using mysql, I looked up `FIND_IN_SET` and applied it as: `FIND_IN_SET(i.id, ?)` but it seems that either my understanding of how it works is wrong, or it simply does not work in this manner. Could you provide me with a brief example of the work around you mentioned? Thanks!!

Comment: @MarcB Also, after a bit of thought... Understand what you have said. If it treated the string as in `1,2` (two id's) then surely no match would be returned at all. Whereas I have a match? It throws up the price of the first item only... Or would it find the `1` meet the `,` and give up there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this here since it's too ugly in a comment. Note the quotes around the `in()` values - that forces them to be a monolithic string, not individual values to be checked agains.

```
mysql> create table foo (bar int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> insert into foo (bar) values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from foo where bar in ('1,2');
+------+
| bar  |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from foo where bar in ('2,1');
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

so, yes, you're getting a match because the value in the field happens to match the first value in the CSV you're putting into the placeholder. MySQL has pretty much the same semantics for converting strings->ints as any other scripting language - all digits from the start of the string up to the first non-digit are treated as the number to be converted, and the rest is thrown away.